# How to call a function in AngularJS only once as initialisation

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

I'm just new to AngularJS and try to create a little app with sqlite.
Now I'm able to insert records and the next step is to delete them by their index.

As I see now it seems that I created an infinite loop because when I start my app it initialize with getting all records from the database.
And this init() causes me trouble.

```
var listApp = angular.module('listApp', []);
listApp.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function ($scope, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    function init() {
        // first - create the table
        createTableIfNotExists();
        getLists();
        console.log("init loaded");
    }

   // some more functions

    init();

}]);
```

So what I wanted to achieve is that when my app starts it first has to look if there are any records in the database, fetch them and render it in the view.
So that works fine. But now as I added the console.log("init loaded") to my init() I see that the init() is running as a loop.

So every new click to a button isn't able to start because of this loop.

What other way is there to start or fetch only once the datas from the database to feed the view? So far I searched in the AngularJS documentation I couldn't find a function that can call a function of a controller e.g. from the HTML-Template.

**EDIT:**
Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/2biOEwi8JmpSne3mqEEX).

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the new [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/2biOEwi8JmpSne3mqEEX/preview).

Comment: the infinite loop has nothing to do with the code you posted...

Comment: But when I comment the init() at the end of my controller the console is empty.

Comment: sounds like you have more than one `ListCtrl` used in view. Show some markup

Comment: @Tipo Of course if you're not calling it at all. The question is, why is it being called more than once? Can you show the html where the controller is initialized?

Comment: comment init call & move console.log outside of init.. you would again see it printed multiple times

Comment: ok, give me a second. I will create a plunker.

Comment: @HarishR after the init() at the end of my controller I also added a console.log and it appears onyl once.

Comment: ok.. waiting for your plunker

Comment: So the plunker is added to the original post.
When you start firebug or the web inspector you will see that the init() is running in a loop. But when I comment it the database won't initialise and no data will be loaded to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your plunker example, `init()` calls a `getLists()` function, which calls `defaultResultHandler()`, which calls `resetForm()`, which calls `init()` again. Thus the infinite loop.

To answer your question, there is nothing wrong with the way in which you're initializing your data. I often do the same with an `init()` function. The problem is, you are explicitly breaking that pattern by calling it again in another function, which makes it no longer a one-time initialization.

Even without the infinite loop, this is bad design IMO. If you find yourself calling `init()` again after the initial load, it's probably time to step back and think about what you're doing and why.

Comment: OMG!!! I really didn't see that I caused that loop. :-(

I agree calling the init() again isn't the best way. But every time I add a new list I need to refresh the view. Maybe I don't need to use init(). The getLists() should be enough for this.

Also there is another problem. I used the resetForm() and called there the getLists() because everytime I added a new list I want to reset the form. But AngularJS throws an error that I can't reset my form just calling "$scope.list.name" because it is undefined. Why that???

Comment: @Tipo Update the plunker and I'll take a look at it. I just tried replacing init() with getLists() though and I don't get an error.

Comment: I added a new plunker at the end of the original post.

Answer (score 2):

the init is not getting called in loop from the controller, but from the reset form...

and this is how the loop is

> init() => getLists() => promisedQuery() => defaultResultHandler() =>
>   resetForm() => init()